# Can't understand this step in Zeta-function transformations

Tags: summation

Sorry for exceptional dullness, but I can't  understand this step in Zeta-function transformations:
$$ζ(s)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}= \sum_{n=1}^\infty n (\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^s})$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: Write
$$n(\frac{1}{n^s}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^s})=(\frac{n}{n^s}-\frac{n+1}{(n+1)^s})+\frac{1}{(n+1)^s}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{(n+1)^{s}} &=
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{n+1}{(n+1)^{s}}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^{s}} \right] \\
&=
 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}-
 \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}} \\
&=
 \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s-1}} -1 \right)-
 \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}} -1 \right) \\
&=
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s-1}}-
 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{s}} 
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\zeta(z)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{s}}
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{n^{s-1}} - \frac{n}{(n+1)^{s}} \right]
= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n \left[\frac{1}{n^{s}} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^{s}} \right]
\end{align*}